# Jenkins auto build from local branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup jenkins that will fetch the git repo every time the build is trigerred. Right now our requirement is that developers want to push there developed code into the jenkins server and test it before pushing it to the central repo. I have googled and found that we can jenkins can trigger a build if the changes are pushed to the central repo. But, i am not able to figure out how to set the push from local branch to jenkins server and trigger the build.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the developers just test and verify (run the build) their code locally before they push it to the central repo?

Comment: If you want validation before the commit gets merged into master, then either create branches for each developer, or use Gerrit (https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) as Git repository and the Jenkins Gerrit Trigger Plugin to trigger the builds. Gerrit is a code review tool, but it also features nice pre-commit verification integration with Jenkins.